# Error in mex using external header files

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

I have little experience in mex files, so pardon me if this is a trivial question. I have written a simple cpp script which loads two images and shows them, using opencv library. I am trying to mex the script, to use it from matlab. Here is my script

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <mex.h>
#include "mc_convert.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int run(Mat source, Mat target)
{
Mat cimg;

vector<Point> target_samples;
vector<Point> source_samples_chamfered;
vector<Point> source_samples_actual;
// Mat source = imread(argv[1], 0);
// Mat target = imread(argv[2], 0);

double centroid_x_actual, centroid_y_actual;
double centroid_x_chamfered, centroid_y_chamfered;

// Threshold both template and reference image
threshold( target, target, 10, 255, 0 );
cvtColor(target, cimg, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
threshold( source, source, 10, 255, 0 );

imshow("target", target);
imshow("source", source);

return 0;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs,
             const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  CvMat* source = mxArr_to_new_CvMat (prhs[0]);
  CvMat* target = mxArr_to_new_CvMat (prhs[1]);

  run(source, target);

  // plhs[0] = CvMat_to_new_mxArr (psrc);
  cvReleaseMat (&source);
  cvReleaseMat (&target);

}
```

For converting types between CvMat and MxArray, I am using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20927-c-c++-and-matlab-types-convertor) link. When I try to compile the script using mex, I get the following error.

```
mex -cxx -largeArrayDims -I "./" -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/local/include chamfer.cpp -L/usr/local/lib/  -lopencv_calib3d  -lopencv_contrib  -lopencv_core  -lopencv_features2d  -lopencv_flann  -lopencv_gpu  -lopencv_highgui  -lopencv_imgproc  -lopencv_legacy  -lopencv_ml  -lopencv_nonfree  -lopencv_objdetect  -lopencv_ocl  -lopencv_photo  -lopencv_stitching  -lopencv_superres  -lopencv_ts  -lopencv_video  -lopencv_videostab

chamfer.cpp: In function ‘void mexFunction(int, mxArray**, int, const mxArray**)’:
chamfer.cpp:162:46: error: ‘mxArr_to_new_CvMat’ was not declared in this scope

mex: compile of ' "chamfer.cpp"' failed.
```

"mxArr_to_new_CvMat" is declared in a file named mc_convert.cpp, which is part of the type conversion library. I have placed all the header and cpp files of the external library in the same folder containing chamfer.cpp. Please help. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

In `mc_convert.h`, `mxArr_to_new_CvMat()` is only declared if preprocessor symbol (macro) `HAS_OPENCV` is defined.  And, in fact, in doc.htm in the the "C/C++ Matlab converter" download it says you should declare this macro.  Try adding `-DHAS_OPENCV` to your mex command.

Comment: Thanks. I added the macro, and it seems this error is fixed. But now it's unable to file cxtypes.h included in mc_convert.h, throwing a fatal error. I cannot find cxtypes.h in the opencv included directory.